# Multiclient server using fork how support rdma rsocket

Tags: sockets, server, fork, rdma

Now we want to support rdma in our old server and client procces.
Before we use  server listen tcp socket and accept client connection. Then fork a new child process to handle the client process.

It looks like there is limitation supporting fork in rsocket. Is there some solution for this scenario? How should we support rdma in our server process?

Comment: Can you use multiple threads instead of forking?

Comment: No we cannot. we must use muliple subprocess. Now I think a complex solution. Use standard socket listen in server main process. Client use standard socket connect with server. After fork, server subprocess begin to create and listen new rsocket. Client connect server with rsocket again.  Then server and client both close old stander socket. I cannot think out better suliton.

Comment: I guess that if each subprocess creates its own listening socket it should work.